# Sql Hierarchy loop query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This table represents a category hierarchy and the element at top of the hierarchy has the parent id as NULL. The table is as the exaple below:

```
**categoryId categoryName parentId**

1           Home         NULL
.           .            .
.           .            .
20          Vehicles      1
.           .           .
35          SUV          20
36          Motorbikes   20
.            .           .
90          BMW          35
91          Toyota       35
.            .           .
234         LandCruiser  91 

Home>Vehicles>SUV>Toyota>LandCruiser
```

What I am trying to do is to bulild up a sql query which will return me back:

[categoryId],[categoryName] chain of any given [categoryId]. It should loop and get each row until it reaches the row with the parentId==NULL.

As the sample example above  234->91->35->20->1->NULL(STOP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
   select
      t.categoryId, t.categoryName, t.parentId,
      cast(t.categoryId as nvarchar(max)) as path
   from categories as t
   where t.categoryId = 234

   union all

   select
      c.categoryId, c.categoryName, t.parentId,
      c.path + '->' + cast(t.categoryId as nvarchar(max))
   from categories as t
       inner join cte as c on c.parentId = t.categoryId
)
select categoryid, categoryname, path + '->NULL'
from cte
where parentid is null
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e878a/4)

Comment: There should be a input for example when we give an input as 234 the query should retrun back the list of the parents until it reaches the parent which parentId is null. I tried but couldnt figure out to modify it. Thanks for reply